# strpos in C- how does it work

Tags: c

I am really new to C.

I want to use the strpos function but it is telling me it doesnt exist?

Comment: What should `strpos` do?  What are the types and the numbers of its parameters, and what's the return value?  Since the C standard doesn't define `strpos()`, and POSIX doesn't either, you should.  The name `strpos` is reserved in C, so ideally you would want to call your function something else, `posstr` for example.

Comment: @Alok Can you give a source for `strpos` being reserved in C?

Comment: `strpos()` was a library function in Traditional C, before standardization. Refer to Harbison&Steele 5th Ed., section 13.5 "strchr, strrchr, ..." pages 351-352.
Yes, I know it's been 12 years ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The function you are looking for might be either strstr or strchr. You then need to include string.h. There is no strpos in the POSIX interface.

Answer (score 27):

Here a complete snippet code to solve you problem.
***PS**: Isn't too late to help. ;)*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NOT_FOUND -1

int main (){
    int pos = NOT_FOUND;
    if ( (pos = strpos( "subsstring", "string")) != NOT_FOUND )
        printf("found at %d\n", pos);
    else
        printf("not found!\n");
    return 0;
}

int strpos(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
   const char *p = strstr(haystack, needle);
   if (p)
      return p - haystack;
   return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

*Edit*: Answering Can Vural question:

No. I really think that it would be as it is. At structured programming paradigm, it's a common practice to use the scope structure as first parameter on every function that belongs to the structure's scope itself. The strstr function defined at string.h follow the same approach.

On OOP you have `haystack.indexOf( needle )`. At structured programming, you have `indexOf( haystack, needle )`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `strpos("string", "substring")`

Comment: Can Vural, I've edited my answer by including some additional explanations about your question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's called `strstr`, related to `strpos` like (pseudo-code):

```
strpos(str, target) {
   res = strstr(str, target); 
   if (res == NULL) return false;
   else             return res - str;
}
```

Comment: Probably should be return -1; instead of return false; for valid results of 0 to strlen(str)-strlen(target)... strpos isn't included in standard, afaik, because the NULL test and subtract generally most efficient inlined so it was felt superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

I have written strpos() function from scratch with position feature(Like PHP's strpos() function). Return value will be starting position of searched string. Enjoy! :)

> In this example code output will be 12

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int strpos(char *haystack, char *needle, int pos);

int main(){

    printf("%d",strpos("abcdefabcdefabcdef asdfgavcabcddd","abc",10));

    return 0;
}

int strpos(char *haystack, char *needle, int pos){
    int i,j,check,result = -1;
    int len_needle=strlen(needle);
    int len_haystack=strlen(haystack);  
    i = pos;
    if (len_needle>len_haystack || *needle==NULL || i>(len_haystack-1)) return result;

    for(;i<len_haystack;i++){
        check = 0;
        for(j=0;j<len_needle;j++){
            if(haystack[i+j]==needle[j]){
                check++;
            }
        }           
        if(check==len_needle){
            result = i;
            break;
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to Miere and Can Vural. I can't add comments yet so will add this as an answer.

> Shouldn't it be strpos("string", "substring") – Can Vural
>
> At structured programming, you have indexOf( haystack, needle ). Miere

In your code, you have:

```
int strpos(char *haystack, char *needle)
```

but you also have:

```
(pos = strpos( "subsstring", "string"))
```

I fully agree with the "int strpos(char *haystack, char *needle)" where the string to be searched comes first and the string to search FOR comes second. But to me, "subsstring" (in the context of "one is a substring and one is a string"), "subsstring" implies that IT is the shorter of the two and that you're trying to find "substring" in "string."

So the one part:

```
(pos = strpos( "subsstring", "string"))
```

should be:

```
(pos = strpos( "string" /*that which is being searched within*/, "substring" /*that which is being searched for in the previous parameter*/))
```

which would be the same as:

```
(pos = strpos( "haystack", "needle"))
```

*Edit: One of the C comments above wasn't closed properly due to a typo.*

Comment: int strpos(char *haystack, char *needle)

brilliant names

Answer (score 0):

There is no function `strpos` defined in the Standard C library nor in the POSIX Standard.  PHP has a function `strpos` with this definition:

```
strpos(string $haystack, string $needle, int $offset = 0): int|false
```

This function locates a substring `needle` inside a string `haystack` and returns the offset from the beginning of the string `haystack`.

C has function `strstr` that can be used for this purpose and returns a pointer to the substring or `NULL` if no match is found:

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

Here is an implementation for a C equivalent of `strpos` relying on `strstr` for the dirty work. Note however that the name `strpos` is reserved for future functions in `<string.h>`:

```
#include <string.h>

int strpos(const char *haystack, const char *needle, int offset) {
    char *p;
    size_t len, pos;

    len = strlen(haystack);
    pos = 0;
    if (offset < 0) {
        if (len > INT_MAX || offset < -(int)len)
            pos = len + offset;
    } else {
        if (len <= INT_MAX && offset > len)
            return NULL;
        pos = offset;
    }
    p = strstr(haystack + pos, needle);
    if (p != NULL && p - haystack <= INT_MAX)
        return (int)(p - haystack);
    else
        return -1;
}
```